# Parse.com says "invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value"

Tags: json, parse-platform, quoting

When I click finish import, Parse.com says "invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value". However, there is not a single character "\" in my entire file. You can check it below.

Apparently, this is because of using single quotes instead of double quotes.
Can I use `"name": 'Samat',` instead of `"name": "Samat"`?

https://gist.github.com/samatdav/61db29a676da21dc4bbd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JSON format specification](http://json.org/) is very clear about this: String values must be enclosed in double quotes. Single quotes or unquoted values (other than true, false, null, numbers or nested object/array definitions) are not allowed.

JavaScript's internal object notation is much less strict in that regard, as it generally allows single-quoted strings. However, JSON is only a subset of the original JavaScript object notation syntax.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that might need this later.
As `ipfs daemon --help` suggests, the cors domain can be set via

`>ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin '["*"]'`

which in Windows yields

Error: failed to unmarshal json. invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value

The correct version should be

`>ipfs config --json API.HTTPHeaders.Access-Control-Allow-Origin "[\"*\"]"`

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is telling you the invalid character is `'` the single quote. It's just represented as a `\'` since they are using single quotes to enclose the invalid character the character must be escaped.

```
"invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value"
                   ^  ^ notice the single quotes.
```

The issue in your gist is that single quotes are not valid representation of strings in JSON.

Note

```
{
    "foo": 'bar'
}
```

Yields the following error on JSONLint

```
Parse error on line 2:
{    "foo": 'bar'}
------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```